# CSharp files modified on open

Tags: find-file, buffer-modified, csharp-mode

When I open files that default to `csharp-mode`, they always start modified. This is only occurring for `csharp-mode`.

`save-buffers-kill-emacs` with the `d` option (view changes in this buffer) shows

> Diff finished (no differences).

How can I stop `.cs` files from being modified when I open them? Why are they being modified?

EDIT:

- files are not modified if reloaded using `revert-buffer`.
- files are modified after running `emacs -Q`, `package-initialize`, and then opening the file (which defaults to `csharp-mode`)
- files are modified after running `emacs -Q`, `package-initialize`, opening a C# file with a fake extension (file is not modified at this point), `csharp-mode` (file is now modified)

Filed a [bug report](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/issues/90) with `csharp-mode`.

Comment: If you revert the buffer after you open file does the buffer still show it was modified?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with `emacs -Q`, `M-x package-initialize` and `M-x csharp-mode` in a suitable buffer?  If yes, please open [a bug report](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/issues/new).

Comment: @wasamasa See my edits. I will be filing a bug report.

Comment: @Melioratus See my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with `csharp-mode`.

Fixed in melpa version `20160909.801`.

See the bug report [here](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/issues/90).